# MySQL Column names of any Select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a SQL teaching program. The students will become their Database and Questions. I want to make it possible for them to write any query they want to and give them the result of it.

So it is possible that they write a query like:

```
SELECT Person.*, Student.ID
FROM Person JOIN Student JOIN Address
WHERE Address.housenr > 20
```

This makes it hard to use the

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

to get the column names. It would be very nice to get those names right from the results of the query. Is it possible to do that in PHP?

Comment: Immediately you should see a problem with this approach.  How do plan to restrict users from selecting wrong column names?  I think your program should be hitting information schema before they write the query.

Comment: Which API do you use to access the database?

Comment: mysqli for now.

Comment: @Shuumi, you may also be interested in checking out the [cseducators.se] community.  It sounds like it might be up your alley.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fetch_fields()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) method to get any information about the columns in your result set. When your query returns at least one row you can use the normal [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) method and read the keys from the returned array via [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).